# How can I get 'key' and 'value' from parsed JSON in python

Tags: python, json

Today I'm trying to do little tricky thing.

I'm trying to get key and value from parsed JSON like this:

```
[{'minecraft.net': 'green'}, {'session.minecraft.net': 'green'}, {'account.mojang.com': 'green'}, {'authserver.mojang.com': 'green'}, {'sessionserver.mojang.com': 'red'}, {'api.mojang.com': 'green'}, {'textures.minecraft.net': 'green'}, {'mojang.com': 'green'}]
```

So I will say example:

```
[{"test1":"test2"}]
```

So test1 is an key and test2 is an value.

and I want to get these values!

```
for data in json:
print(data.key) # This should return the test1 string
print(data.value) # This sould return the test2 string
```

But this is not working. So If there anybody know how could I achive that! Please tell me!

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON, this is about dictionaries.

Comment: You said it really early bruh

Comment: What? You need to look at [ask] and the [help]

Comment: The API is returning JSON soooo.... I'm working with JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you receive when you load json data, is native Python Dict, or List.
When you're iterating over a list of dictionaries as you do here, `data` is a dict.

To extract a value from a dict, you need to look up the key by its name, in your instance: `'minecraft.net', 'session.minecraft.net', 'account.mojang.com', ...`

Python dictionaries are accessed like so: `data["minecraft.net"]` (returns "green")

Easiest to do would be (following your setup):

```
for data in json:
    for key, value in data.items():
        print(key)
        print(value)
```

Essentially:

```
for dictionary in list:
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        print(key)
        print(value)
```

Read more: [w3schools: Python Loop Through a Dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_loop_dictionary_items.asp)

(edit): Summary

Unclear in the question, but variable 'json' was a file-like object.
Resolved issue with:

```
json = json.load(json)
```

Comment: This assumes that json is indeed a list of dictionaries, import native library called "json" and use: json.loads(<json_string>) to get it working properly.

Comment: Your code is returning this 
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Then it seems your "json" variable is not a list, it is a bytes object. How do you load the json data? Try using: with open("file.json") as f: json = json.load(f.read())

Comment: I'm not reading from file, I'm requesting the JSON from API

Comment: Then try using json = json.load(json) to utilize the JSON library to turn that bytes-like object into a list of dicts :) (note: json.loads() expects a string, but json.load() expects a bytes-like object)

Comment: @Sonder `json.load` will throw an error if you pass it a bytes-like object, it expects a file-like object.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh, you're right, my bad. Turning the bytes-like object to string and then use json.loads() would fix that. Though, seems that variable "json" from the question was a file-like object after all. So worked out.

Answer (score 0):

```
json = [{'minecraft.net': 'green'}, {'session.minecraft.net': 'green'}, {'account.mojang.com': 'green'}, {'authserver.mojang.com': 'green'}, {
    'sessionserver.mojang.com': 'red'}, {'api.mojang.com': 'green'}, {'textures.minecraft.net': 'green'}, {'mojang.com': 'green'}]
for data in json:
    for key in data:
        print(key)
        print(data[key])
```

gives me:

```
green
session.minecraft.net
green
account.mojang.com
green
authserver.mojang.com
green
sessionserver.mojang.com
red
api.mojang.com
green
textures.minecraft.net
green
mojang.com
green
PS C:\Users\jonas\OneDrive\Desktop\seconddesktop\newLocalWebsite> & C:/Users/jonas/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/jonas/OneDrive/Desktop/seconddesktop/newLocalWebsite/react-folder/src/components/test.py       
minecraft.net
green
session.minecraft.net
green
account.mojang.com
green
authserver.mojang.com
green
sessionserver.mojang.com
red
api.mojang.com
green
textures.minecraft.net
green
mojang.com
green
```

By iterating over the dict you get the keys, by writing `data[key]`, you get the values!

Comment: This is not working when using parsed json and when using not parsed json it will print bunch of random numbers and type an error

Comment: Can you give me an example of a json that won't work? With your two examples it gave me the right output!

Comment: @Pixeluted "not working" is not a useful problem description.

Comment: I'm using this JSON when using your code

[{'minecraft.net': 'green'}, {'session.minecraft.net': 'green'}, {'account.mojang.com': 'green'}, {'authserver.mojang.com': 'green'}, {'sessionserver.mojang.com': 'red'}, {'api.mojang.com': 'green'}, {'textures.minecraft.net': 'green'}, {'mojang.com': 'green'}]

Comment: @Pixeluted what you've posted is not JSON, that is a list of dicts

Comment: Stop it, we now all know it